How would you translate the Spanish "malteco" into English?
Birthday wish:  feliz cumpli 'malteco'

What is the context and/or country of use of "malteco"?

https://www.asale.org/damer/manteco es lo más parecido que escuché. Parece que es un argot colombiano para tipos que se follan a la empleada doméstica. No creo que haya una buena traducción para eso, más que concatenar varios epítetos. Y ni se te ocurra decir ‘feliz cumple, manteco’.

Portuguese speakers would imagine it's from their word "malta" meaning club or gang, but I'm not finding the same word in any Spanish dictionaries, so unless this is a bilingual pun it must not be that.

La palabra "malteco" se refiere a algo o alguien originario de Malta, una isla situada en el mar Mediterráneo. Es un gentilicio que se usa para describir a las personas de Malta o cualquier cosa relacionada con este país.

@user37164 el gentilicio es maltés

It's a diminuitive of maltés, isn't it?

https://www.asale.org/damer/-eco no conozco el uso como diminutivo, pero chances hay

If they wish a bottle of rum as a birthday present, no translation is needed.

Uuuuuuuu es buenísima esa! Mi jeva es una adicta , creo que en su próximo cumpleaños le voy a decir la frase del OP

Es necesario un contexto. De tener un amigo gutemalteco, también le diría "feliz cumple 'malteco'".

CIERREN ESTA PREGUNTA DE UNA BUENA VEZ, LPM! me pone nervioso que dejen estas preguntas abiertas

BUENO ME CANSÉ BOY A RESPONDER

Un malteco es un mal teco. Descomponiendo la palabra nos topamos con que la segunda abre una bifurcación hacia dos posibles caminos:

teco, -a.
I. 1.  adj. Ch. Relativo a México. pop ^ fest.
II. (Apóc. de tecolote).

adj/sust. Gu. Referido a persona, borracha. pop.


O sea que en realidad, o la persona es un ‘mal mexicano’, en el sentido de que no sabe como ser o actuar de mexica―un ‘mexicano trucho’, como se diría por acá. O bien es un ‘mal borracho’, en el sentido de que no sabe cómo ponerse en pedo. En cualquiera de los dos casos, mal debe entenderse como male, no como malum.
Dependiendo del contexto, las dos posibilidades son:

Happy birthday, noob mexican!
Happy birthday, noob drinker!

